# AWS API-Gateway Authentication Headers required

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication

Here is my scenario:

Have have a UserPool and an IdentityPool setup via Cognito. I also have an API-Gateway endpoint cofigured to authenticate with AWS_AIM.

First I log a user into the Cognito UserPool using their username and password. The response I receive is positive and looks like the following:

```
[AuthenticationResult] => Array
                (
                    [AccessToken] => <AccessToken>
                    [ExpiresIn] => 3600
                    [TokenType] => Bearer
                    [RefreshToken] => <RefreshToken>
                    [IdToken] => <IdToken>
                )
```

Using this information, I authorise the user with the Cognito IdentityPool. The response I receive is positive and looks like the following:

```
            [IdentityId] => <IdentityId>
            [Credentials] => Array
                (
                    [AccessKeyId] => <AccessKeyId>
                    [SecretKey] => <SecretKey>
                    [SessionToken] => <SessionToken>
                    [Expiration] => Aws\Api\DateTimeResult Object
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-06-15 09:11:32.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 1
                            [timezone] => +00:00
                        )

                )
```

And this is where I am stuck. I need the following headers in order to make the actual request to the API-Gateway Endpoint:

```
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 
Credential=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE/20130524/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request, 
SignedHeaders=host;range;x-amz-date,
```

Signature=fe5f80f77d5fa3beca038a248ff027d0445342fe2855ddc963176630326f1024

But for the life of me I can't find a way to generate these headers. And the AWS SDK Documentation sets for Javascript and PHP is not particularly clear on what exactly to do. So my geuss is I missed a bit somewhere. Does any one have any knowledge on how to correctly generate these headers? Preferably using PHP.

Comment: Any AWS SDK should add this for you, if you simply tell it to use these new credentials to access the desired resource.  But... it's not clear how/why you are using the user's credentials to access API Gateway from your server -- or perhaps that isn't what you're actually doing -- your question seems unclear in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not well with PHP, but I know you need SignatureV4 signed request...isn't this what you are looking for? 
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/Signature/SignatureV4.php#L42